# What are the disadvantages of developing android using cross platform languages?

Tags: java, android, react-native, xamarin, cross-platform

I started to learn android development in Java and followed that path up to now.
Nowadays there are many cross platforms development languages such as Xamarin, React Native and etc.

I know that I can develop for both iOS and Android in cross platform languages which is usually requested by customers to develop mobile app in these two platforms.

Now my question is what is the benefit for developing in native android and iOS platforms over using cross platform languages?

I think if I have not enough reason to stuck to native development, I could not satisfy my customer to develop their app in native languages and I need to migrate to cross-platform languages.

So I want to know are there any bold benefits for native development or not?

Comment: imo xamarin is buggy and difficult to work with. You can end up putting a lot of work into a cross platform app and it can be work taking the original cost of writing two separate apps. My personal opinion only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those endless debates in development. There are so many reasons to go either way.

**Native Benefits:**

- Best possible user experience
- Access to all the features of the os and hardware
- Smaller and faster applications (especially UI responsiveness)
- Often easier to maintain (no need to deal with platform bugs)
- Quicker response to o.s. changes

**Cross-platform Benefits**

- Faster development to access the larger user base
- Easier development - no need to learn as much about each native system
- Powerful integration options (Cloud, Security, Game Engines, etc.)

For involved UI, I suggest that building your UI to target the native platform and everything else to be cross-platform. It is important to understand how important the user experience is to the success of the app you are making. Something simple like accessing some data from the web and showing a chart will look fine in a cross-platform app. Doing advanced image manipulation will likely require native UI to feel right.

The bottom line is "it depends on the project"

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your project requirement to develop native app or hybrid app.

**Choose native development if**

1. High performance
2. You want a fluid, high responsive user interface
3. The user interface should feel familiar to users on each platform
4. Your application needs full access to all device hardware and functionality.

**Choose cross-platform development if**

1. You want to develop a quick prototype to test and validate a simple concept
2. Your application has a simple user interface and has limited user interaction, such as listing and showing news content
3. Your user interface has limited scrolling and swiping and users will not be affected by a sluggish screen response
4. Your application does not process complex data or work with audio or video

Comment: Native development is a good choice for specific list of devices, which work on only one OS. E.g. Android devices which will be bought or are in-service is for native development. Whereas Bring Your Own Device idea is good fit for cross-platform (or "hybrid") development.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-platform development is *not a silver bullet*.

Taking decisions about changing from native development to hip frameworks and cross-platform tools, you need to understand specifics of implementing same features in terms of this cross-platform tools. And this can be a problem in itself, because you will need experience with cross-platforming.

Cross-platform tools are *cool* as in "it will be a single codebase", but in some cases they are *not*. Different OS means different UI / UX, services and underlining implementations, as they *form* according APIs. It is baffling to see a React Native project with different set of modules written for specifics of Android and iOS, just to understand that *this exact project* should have been written as separate native applications all along.

So, before developing, take a quick dive into specific cross-platform tooling you think will be the best and you will understand implications of using this tooling for your project.

Answer (score 0):

So just use Kotlin. Kotlin is interoperable with Java and working with JVM, but also has native compiler for iOS. Of course development for both platforms makes some limits, but if you want to create cross platform application it may be useful for you.